# Dependency Property GetValue returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a declared a custom `TriggerAction` in my XAML and I bind an Command to it.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="data">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBox Width="150" Name="styleTb">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <behaviors:TextChangedTrigger TextChangedCommand="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But when I try to get the value via the `GetValue` method, it returns `null`.

This is how the class looks like

```
public class TextChangedTrigger : TriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand),
                                                                                                        typeof(TextChangedTrigger));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Command which will be executed.
    /// </summary>
    public  ICommand TextChangedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the TextChangedCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        object test = GetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty); // Returns null
    }
```

Why does it return null?

Comment: How about just using `object test = TextChangedCommand;`?

Comment: @MikeEason it does not work

Comment: See my answer . I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually set the value of the TextChangedCommand property to anything.

Either set it some value in a constructor for the TextChangedTrigger class or use the [DependencyProperty.Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that allows for setting a default value.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextChangedCommand",
    typeof(ICommand),
    typeof(TextChangedTrigger),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new WhateverYourCommandIs());
```